# Why do Chrome and Internet Explorer return different values for HttpContext LogonUserIdentity when debugging?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, visual-studio-2017, windows-authentication

I have an application using Windows Authentication on IIS, and I retrieve the username using

```
WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

in my authorization code. The windows account I log in to does not have local admin permissions for security reasons, so I have to run Visual Studios as Administrator using different log-in credentials.

When I debug using Google Chrome, the above code sets the identity.Name attribute to the username of the account logged into my computer, which is what I expected, but when I debug using Internet Explorer, the above code sets identity.Name to the username of the local admin account that I logged into to run Visual Studio as an administrator.

What causes the discrepancy between the values returned by the same code depending on which browser I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Windows Authentication/ disable Anonymous Authentication from Visual Studio? The following link show the outcomes for different settings.

https://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net/

Comment: I enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication from IIS. The results are the same no matter which of the methods I use in that article, in Internet Explorer the ladm account is returned and in Chrome, the global account is returned. Is there a place in Visual Studio that I also need to change to Windows Authentication for the project/solution? I can't seem to find a setting for that in the properties.

Comment: (VS 2015 => View Menu => Properties Windows)  / F4  , click on the project, you should be able to see the windows.  Under Developement Server, you can select the drop down for Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication.